# How to upload image to s3 with lambda and API gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload an image to s3 with lambda and Api gateway when i submit form how can i do it in python.

currently i am getting this error while i am trying to upload image through PostMan

```
Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: Unexpected character (\'-\' (code 45))
```

my code currently is

```
import json
import boto3
import base64

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    try:
        if event['httpMethod'] == 'POST' : 
            print(event['body'])
            data = json.loads(event['body'])
            name = data['name']
            image = data['file']
            image = image[image.find(",")+1:]
            dec = base64.b64decode(image + "===")
            s3.put_object(Bucket='', Key="", Body=dec)
            return {'statusCode': 200, 'body': json.dumps({'message': 'successful lambda function call'}), 'headers': {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}}
    except Exception as e:
        return{
            'body':json.dumps(e)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing an upload through API Gateway and Lambda has its limitations:
You can not handle large files and there is an execution timeout of 30 seconds as I recall.
I would go with creating a presigned url that is requested by the client through API gateway, then use it as the endpoint to put the file.

Something like this will go in your Lambda ,

(This is a NodeJs example)

```
const uploadUrl = S3.getSignedUrl( 'putObject', {
                Bucket: get(aPicture, 'Bucket'),
                Key: get( aPicture, 'Key'),
                Expires: 600,
            })
    callback( null, { url })
```

(NodeJs)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property

(Python)
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Lambda for this. You can proxy S3 API with API Gateway
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html

Answer (score 0):

Ooops it's over engineering.

anyways, it's seems like your are getting error from API-gateway, first check the lambda through "test lambda" using aws console, if it's working fine and getting the response back from lambda then please check with API-gateway side.

i doubt you are using some mapping templates in gateway, AWS uses AWS Velocity templates, which looks like JSON, but it's different. those mapping template at integration request causing this issue.